# Accessing Asynchronous Web Service Methods in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7

I am trying, very simply, to make an asynchronous call to a web service method and get a return value. I'm doing this in Visual Studio 2010, with its service reference proxy class feature. Strangely enough, the resources for this are few and far between, and most of them are outdated, using Begin[Method] and End[Method] rather than [Method]Async and [Method]Completed.

I'm attempting to follow this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55xs7d7f(v=vs.80).aspx. When the event denoting that the method has returned is raised, I always get a result of null.

```
MyWebServiceClient client = new MyWebServiceClient();
client.webMethodCompleted += 
    new System.EventHandler<webMethodCompletedArgs>(Callback);
client.webMethodAsync();
```

Later in the code, the `Callback` method:

```
void Callback(object sender, webMethodCompletedArgs args)
{
    string data = args.Result;
}
```

The problem is, if I run this code, `args.Result` will always be `null`. I have tested the web service using a synchronous interface, which works just fine, so I know it's not the web service. I'm new to this stuff, so I'm probably doing something wrong that's really simple.

Comment: I don't know WinPhone development, but you're using the old ASMX technology to access the service (Web Reference). You should try using a Service Reference instead.

Comment: Thank you for responding, John. I did originally add the service through the "Service References" folder in Visual Studio. I didn't see a "Web References" folder anywhere. Is there something that I'm missing, or something I should have done when adding the reference to not use the ASMX tech?

Comment: Yes, you should simply use "Add Service Reference" and ignore web references entirely.

Comment: That's what I did. There were never any web references, unless there's something I missed.

Comment: Ok, maybe I confused you. The link you posted was to a .NET 2.0 article about using web references. You should pay no attention to what's in that article.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

If args.Result is null then the args.Error property should be populated with the exception that happened.

Comment: Under normal operation, if Cancelled is false and Error is null, then Result should contain whatever the result of the operation was. Is it possible the service is returning succesfully but an empty value?

Comment: It's possible, but highly unlikely. When I use the synchronous version, it works fine and returns what it's supposed to (which is not null).

Comment: I would get a trace of the data on the wire. Since you are sending from the phone maybe something is different about the request.